# Segmentation fault in C with fread and fwrite even though I used malloc

Tags: c, file-io, malloc

I have been working on a program that keeps crashing due to segmentation fault. I cropped out the simplest part of the code causing this issue.
According to what I learnt so far, if I ask the OS for memory allocation, and then use the pointer to read&write to that address of the memory, it should be good to go.

In this case, the following snipped looks pretty simple to me: opening a new file for writing, opening source file, creating `outdata` to hold enough bytes, reading the exact value of bytes from source and writing to new file with `fwrite` with same parameters.

Is there something fundamental I'm missing here?

```
int main (void)
{
    FILE *outimg = fopen("test.jpg", "w");
    FILE *rawFile = fopen("source.file", "r");
    if(rawFile==NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open source file\n");
      return 1;
    }
    int chunkSize = 512;
    int picChunkCount = 440;
    unsigned char *outdata = malloc(chunkSize*picChunkCount*sizeof(unsigned char));
    if(outdata==NULL)
    {
      fprintf(stderr,"Unable to allocate memory for *outdata\n");
      return 2;
    }
    fread(&outdata, sizeof(unsigned char)*chunkSize*picChunkCount,1, rawFile);
    fwrite(&outdata, sizeof(unsigned char)*chunkSize*picChunkCount, 1, outimg);
}
```

Comment: Not checking the return code of `fopen`, and just going on as if nothing is wrong is one such flaw.  If `fopen` fails, a `NULL` is returned.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, you're right. Actually my main code included a check for that but I removed it to provide a more brief snippet here. I also free'ed my variables before the code ends, but since it didn't solve the problem I removed these lines too.

Comment: *but I removed it to provide a more brief snippet here.* -- You should not have removed it.  Your question explicitly asks why a segmentation fault occurs.  Looking at the code, `outimg` or `rawFile` being NULL would be one reason.

Comment: ok, I've added lines to check null status

Comment: `fread(&outdata` stop right here. This is not how fread works. Read the manual again. What does it say about the first argument?

Comment: @n.m. as follows: `size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream);` and for the first argument: `"Storing them at the location given by ptr".` So, I thought I would be reading XYZ bytes of data, and storing them in the location of outdata ptr which is allocated by malloc above, is that wrong?

Comment: `outdata` *is* a pointer. It's *value* already *points* to a location, namely the one allocated my the call to `malloc()`.

Comment: I removed "&" sign from both fread and fwrite, now the output file has calculated size of bytes as I desired. Can you post as a reply so I can choose as solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove `&` in `fread` and `fwrite`.

That's because `outdata` *already* points to location, allocated by `malloc()`.

P.S. Don't forget to `free(outdata);`

Answer (score 2):

Two things are missing:

- You're reading and writing *bytes*, so you need to specify fopen parameters to wb and rb
- Not checking the return of fopen, fwrite and error while memory allocation.

Finally, it's better to allocate memory consistently: if your file weighs 20Gb, but only 10Gb RAM available – something bad will happen.

Try to use this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHUNK 512

int main () {
    FILE *inputFile;
    FILE *outputFile;
    unsigned char *buffer;
    size_t nread;

    buffer = malloc(CHUNK);
    if (!buffer) exit(1);

    inputFile  = fopen("input.txt", "rb");
    outputFile = fopen("output.txt", "wb");

    if (!inputFile || !outputFile) exit(2);

    while ((nread = fread(buffer, 1, CHUNK, inputFile)) > 0)
        fwrite(buffer, 1, nread, outputFile);

    if (ferror(inputFile) || ferror(outputFile)) exit(3);

    free(buffer);
    fclose(inputFile);
    fclose(outputFile);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C there is no need to cast `void`-pointers, nor is it recommended in way way to do so.

Comment: @alk, No, it is important to use `> 0`, because fread returns the number of elements successfully read, but not the chunk size. If file has been split to 10 pieces (1024 bytes), but the last one is 200 bytes - what would happen if I compare with CHUNK?

Comment: Sry, you are correct. This was a temp brain-laps from my side .That's why I deleted my comment more or less immediately.