# How would I read the contents of a large file in the heap without memory errors

Tags: c

The question I am asking is extremely simple. Lets just say I wanted to read a large file(6GB) without having the heap run out of memory. How would I do that. (What I am mainly asking is if there is a method to read part of the file clear the buffer and read the next part of the file)

Comment: Which language, C or C++?  There could be a difference.  The C++ language has `operator new` and `placement new`, which are not in the C language.

Comment: Im mainly asking for c

Comment: You want to allocate a file in memory part-by-part? But there're no reason to keep the whole file in memory. You have to read data and put it in buffer. Then you've to do something with it, and then - free buffer.Or you want to copy file part-by-part?

Comment: I would like to copy it

Comment: To copy file, allocating memory consistently, use the code in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940876/segmentation-fault-in-c-with-fread-and-fwrite-even-though-i-used-malloc/41941277#41941277)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory capacity and availability is platform and operating system dependent.

Some operating systems allow for *memory mapping* a file, in which the operating system manages the reading of data into memory for you.

Reading without overflow is accomplished by using *block* reading (a.k.a. `fread` in C and `istream::read` in C++).  You tell the input function how much to read in the block and the function returns the quantity actually read.  The block size should be less than or equal to the memory allocated for the data.  The next read will start a the next location in the file.  Perform in a loop to read in all the data.

Also, verify there is a reason to hold all the data in memory at the same time.   Most programs only hold a small portion of the data for a limited time.